# Is there a way a TextBox loses focus when clicking on the background in Caliburn Micro?

Tags: c#, .net, caliburn.micro

When trying to rebuild a WPF Application to use Caliburn Micro I experienced that a `TextBox` does not loose focus when you click outside of it. Is there a fix for that behaviour?

I am using Caliburn Micro 3.2.0. I tried using older versions but this problem persits.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFUI.Views.ShellView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFUI.Views"
        xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ShellView" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        ...
        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBox x:Name="Name"  MinWidth="50"  
                     cal:Message.Attach="[Event LostFocus] = [Action Name_LostFocus()];
                     [Event PreviewTextInput] = [Action Name_PreviewTextInput($source, $eventArgs)]">
            </TextBox>
            ...
        </WrapPanel>
        ...
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is a case where you do not have any other Element in the Window other than the Textbox, which is why it cannot lose focus. One way to achieve this is to make the Window Focusable and setting Focus to it using a behavior.

For Example, assuming your Xaml to be as follows

```
<Window x:Class="CM.WPFApp2019.Views.ShellView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CM.WPFApp2019.Views"
        xmlns:i = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
        xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:CM.WPFApp2019.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d" Focusable="True"
        Title="ShellView" Height="450" Width="800">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:ClearFocusOnClickBehavior ElementToClearFocus="{Binding ElementName=Name}"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Grid>
        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBox x:Name="Name"  MinWidth="50"  Focusable="True"
                     cal:Message.Attach="[Event LostFocus] = [Action Name_LostFocus()];
                     [Event PreviewTextInput] = [Action Name_PreviewTextInput($source, $eventArgs)]">
            </TextBox>
        </WrapPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Please note I have added a Behavior called `ClearFocusOnClickBehavior` to the Window. Also you have set the Focusable Property of Window to be true.

Now you can define the behavior as follows

```
public class ClearFocusOnClickBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ElementToClearFocusProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ElementToClearFocus", typeof(FrameworkElement), 
                                                                            typeof(ClearFocusOnClickBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata());


        public FrameworkElement ElementToClearFocus
        {
            get { return (FrameworkElement)GetValue(ElementToClearFocusProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ElementToClearFocusProperty, value); }
        }
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            AssociatedObject.MouseDown += (sender, args) => 
            {
                FrameworkElement ctrl = ElementToClearFocus; 
                FrameworkElement parent = (FrameworkElement)ElementToClearFocus.Parent;

                while (parent != null && parent is IInputElement
                                  && !((IInputElement)parent).Focusable)
                {
                    parent = (FrameworkElement)parent.Parent;
                }

                DependencyObject scope = FocusManager.GetFocusScope(ElementToClearFocus); 
                FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(scope, parent as IInputElement);
            };
            base.OnAttached();
        }

    }
```

The Behavior would add a `MouseDown` event for the associated object, where you could trace the `Parent` of the `ElementToClearFocus` Control which can be Focused. In this case, since you have set the Window as focusable, it would receive the Focus. The `Textbox` in turn loses the focus and raises the `Name_LostFocus` method

Comment: I tried your solution and it worked for all TextBoxes. Even changing the ElementToClearFocus to the Grid worked. The Window is Focusable by default, isn't it?

Comment: I put `DependencyObject scope = FocusManager.GetFocusScope((FrameworkElement)sender);
                FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(scope, sender as IInputElement);` in the MouseDown Event Handler and it worked.

Comment: Glad it hear that it worked. Kindly mark it as answer if it helped you resolve the issue